# Stability AI SDKを使用したプロジェクトがローカル環境で正常に動作しない

Tags: python, flask

#### 実現したいこと

- Macのローカル環境でGitHubプロジェクト [stable-diffusion-API](https://github.com/silverbirder/stable-diffusion-API.git) を動作するようにする
- ターミナルから指定のプロジェクトを実行し、Webブラウザにアクセスしたら生成された画像が表示されるようにする

#### 質問内容

最近、私はStability AIのSDKを使用したプロジェクトに取り組んでいます。このプロジェクトは、Stability AIのSDKを用いて、テキストプロンプトに基づいた画像を生成することを目指しています。

しかし、プロジェクトをローカル環境で実行しようとすると、何度試してもうまくいきません。そこで、皆さんの助けを借りて、私の手順に何か問題があるのか、それとも他の要因が関与しているのかを解明したいと思います。

以下に、私がこれまでに試した手順を記載します：

GitHubから[Stable Diffusion API](https://github.com/silverbirder/stable-diffusion-API.git)をクローンしました。
Stability AIのウェブサイトからAPIキーを取得し、.envファイルに保存しました。
Pythonの仮想環境を作成し、プロジェクトの依存関係をインストールしました。
`flask run` を実行してサーバーを起動し、`http://127.0.0.1:5000/?prompt=bird`  にアクセスしました。
しかし、このURLにアクセスすると、内部サーバーエラーが表示されます。また、ターミナルのログには、status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT details = "must provide image parameters" というエラーメッセージが表示されます。

SDKのドキュメントを参照し、さまざまな解決策を試しましたが、うまくいきませんでした。

この問題について知識のある方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけると幸いです。また、他の方が同じ手順を試し、同じ問題が発生するかどうかを確認していただけると大変助かります。

<備考>
この質問について、現在別サイトでも同様の質問を掲載しています。恐れ入りますがご認識の程よろしくお願いいたします。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/kn0e6b6fjafy2e) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 参照したドキュメントや試した解決策も、具体的な情報を記してください。

Comment: 承知しました！以下のように本文に追記しました。

<備考>
この質問について、現在別サイトでも同様の質問を掲載しています。恐れ入りますがご認識の程よろしくお願いいたします。